# New iMac repeatedly crashing every 30 minutess

Tags: catalina, crash, kernel-panic

My new iMac repeatedly crashes every 30 minutes or so, and has done so for the past 2 weeks.

This is the crash report:

Can anyone can give some tips please?

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8010649b8a): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8010a56c4a, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00000000000000a0, CR3: 0x00000008b99af14b, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000003, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff807f905a40, RDX: 0xffffff807f18d338
RSP: 0xffffff84b3f0bd30, RBP: 0xffffff84b3f0be40, RSI: 0x00000000000000a0, RDI: 0xffffff807f18d290
R8:  0xffffff84b3f0be80, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x0000000000000008, R11: 0xffffff807f816d00
R12: 0xffffff807f816d30, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff8010a57820, R15: 0xffffff807fbac980
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff8010a56c4a, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00000000000000a0, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2, PL: 1, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff84b3f0b790 : 0xffffff801051e6dd 
0xffffff84b3f0b7e0 : 0xffffff8010657c25 
0xffffff84b3f0b820 : 0xffffff80106497de 
0xffffff84b3f0b870 : 0xffffff80104c4a40 
0xffffff84b3f0b890 : 0xffffff801051dda7 
0xffffff84b3f0b990 : 0xffffff801051e197 
0xffffff84b3f0b9e0 : 0xffffff8010cc145c 
0xffffff84b3f0ba50 : 0xffffff8010649b8a 
0xffffff84b3f0bbd0 : 0xffffff8010649888 
0xffffff84b3f0bc20 : 0xffffff80104c4a40 
0xffffff84b3f0bc40 : 0xffffff8010a56c4a 
0xffffff84b3f0be40 : 0xffffff8010a58c77 
0xffffff84b3f0bf40 : 0xffffff8010b85d27 
0xffffff84b3f0bfa0 : 0xffffff80104c5206 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Adobe CEF Helper

Mac OS version:
19F72f

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.5.0: Sun Apr 19 22:51:38 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.120.31~14/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FFC5BCD5-8D44-32EE-8F36-A2B8372C434C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000010200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8010400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8010300000
System model name: iMac19,1 (Mac-AA95B1DDAB278B95)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 64133517322788
last loaded kext at 13977990017: >!AActuatorDriver  3440.1 (addr 0xffffff7f93aa8000, size 61440)
last unloaded kext at 190528235691: >!ASMCRTC   1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f92737000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.9
>!AHDA  283.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.9
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.9
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.4
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.4
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.5f3
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.6
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@kext.AMD9500!C 3.0.9
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.427
>eficheck   1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.6
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!UTopCaseDriver    3430.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.120.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@kext.AMDRadeonX4400HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.9
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.4
|IOAVB!F    850.1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.5f3
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.5f3
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.4
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.9
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.4
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.5.3
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.5f3
|IO!B!F 7.0.5f3
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.5f3
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.120.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: i used to be able to read the kext info, but not since they changed the format for Catalina. The crash was in Adobe CEF Helper, though, so first - is your Adobe CC up to date?

Comment: It is a known issue with Catalina 10.15.4. Hopefully will get fixed in the next update. https://www.macrumors.com/2020/04/06/macos-10-5-4-kernel-panic-crashing-issues/

Comment: Try Safe Mode. This prevents third party applications from causing this crash. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262.